# Is there a succinct way to define custom routes within a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

Here's some code I have:

```
resources :things
post "/foo/bar" => "things#create"
```

Is there a more succinct/maintainable way to define the custom post route inside a block given to `resources`?

Comment: I'm not really sure because I didn't try it, but it looks like you need the shallow: true option when putting the route inside a block for resources

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, use this in your routes file:

```
resources :things do
  post 'foo/bar', on: :member, to: 'things#create'
end
```

If you want to create *all* the `things` routes under the `foo` path instead of `things`, use a `path` parameter to the `resources` call:

```
resources :things, path: 'foo'
```

Comment: hm okay, i was hoping that if the directive was inside the `resources :things` block then the controller would be implicit